# Docker + Gunicorn + Nginx + Django: redirect non-www to www on AWS Route 53

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx

I have a Docker + Gunicorn + Nginx + Django setup on AWS EC2 and Route 53. Right now I want to redirect mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com.

Is it appropriate to do a redirect in a Nginx configuration? Or are there are better solutions.

Here is docker-compose-yml, using gunicorn to start the Django server.

```
version: '2'  
services:  
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: dj_nginx
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./src/my_project/static:/static
      - ./src:/src
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: dj_web
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn my_project.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./apps/django_rapid:/src/my_project/django_rapid
    expose:
      - "8000"

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: dj_db
```

Here is my Nginx Conf

```
upstream web {  
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

# portal
server {  
    listen 8000;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web/;
    }

    location /media  {
        alias  /media;  # your Django project  media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias  /static; # your Django project  static files - amend as required
    }

    server_name localhost;
}


# portal (https)                                                                                                   
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name localhost;

    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate    /etc/nginx/conf.d/mynginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/conf.d/mynginx.key;

    location /media  {
        alias  /media;  # your Django project  media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias  /static; # your Django project  static files - amend as required
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's appropriate to do these kinds of redirects in the webserver. If it's https your certificate needs to cover both domains.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's appropriate to do nginx redirections, but i find doing [PREPEND_WWW](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#prepend-www) more simple.

Add this in your **settings.py**

```
PREPEND_WWW = True
```